# flatpickr - Выбор диапозона дат кнопкой

Tags: javascript

Календарь
https://flatpickr.js.org/

Плагин дополнительных кнопок
https://github.com/jcsmorais/shortcut-buttons-flatpickr

```
flatpickr(".flatpickr-input", {
"locale": "ru",
"mode": "multiple",
"showMonths": "3",
"dateFormat": "d.m.Y",

plugins: [
    ShortcutButtonsPlugin({
        button: [
            {
                label: "Последние 7 дней"
            },
            {
                label: "Текущий месяц"
            },
            {
                label: "Прошлый месяц"
            }
        ],
        label: "",
        onClick: (index, fp) => {
            let date;
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                date = new Date(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                date = new Date(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 2000);
                break;
                case 1:
                date = new Date();
                break;
                case 2:
                date = new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                break;
            }
        fp.setDate(date);
        }
    })
]
```

});

Подскажите как заставить кнопку выбрать 7 дней, месяц как на скрине https://skr.sh/s35lTNVtOwB

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
flatpickr(".flatpickr-input", {
    locale: "ru",
    mode: "multiple",

    showMonths: 3,
    dateFormat: "d.m.Y",
    plugins: [
        ShortcutButtonsPlugin({
            button: [
                {
                    label: "Последние 7 дней"
                },
                {
                    label: "Последние 30 дней"
                },
                {
                    label: "Текущий месяц"
                },
                {
                    label: "Прошлый месяц"
                },
                {
                    label: "Последний год"
                },
                {
                    label: "Применить"
                }
            ],
            label: "",
            onClick: (index, fp) => {
                let date;
                switch (index) {
                    // Последние 7 дней
                    case 0:
                        var arr = [];
                        var i = 0;
                        while (i < 7000) {
                            i = i + 1000;
                            arr.push(new Date(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * i));
                            date = arr;
                        }
                    break;
                    // Последние 30 дней
                    case 1:
                        var arr = [];
                        var i = 0;
                        while (i < 30000) {
                            i = i + 1000;
                            arr.push(new Date(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * i));
                            date = arr;
                        }
                    break;
                    // Текущий месяц
                    case 2:
                        Date.prototype.daysInMonth = function() {
                            return 33 - new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 33).getDate();
                        };
                        var days = new Date().daysInMonth(); // Кол-во дней
                        var today = new Date(); // Сегодня
                        //var firstDayOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1); // Первый день
                        //var lastDayOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+1, 0); // Последниый день
                        var arr = [];
                        var i = 0;
                        while (i < days) {
                            i = i + 1;
                            var firstDayOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), i); // Первый день
                            arr.push(firstDayOfMonth);
                            date = arr;
                        }   
                    break;
                    // Прошлый месяц
                    case 3:
                        Date.prototype.daysInMonth = function() {
                            return 33 - new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 33).getDate();
                        };
                        var days = new Date().daysInMonth() - 1; // Кол-во дней
                        var today = new Date(); // Сегодня
                        var firstDayOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 1); // Первый день
                        var arr = [];
                        var i = 0;
                        while (i < days) {
                            i = i + 1;
                            var firstDayOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, i); // Первый день
                            arr.push(firstDayOfMonth);
                            date = arr;
                        }
                    break;
                    // Последний год
                    case 4:
                        var arr = [];
                        var i = 0;
                        while (i < 365000) {
                            i = i + 1000;
                            arr.push(new Date(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * i));
                            date = arr;
                        }
                    break;
                    // Применить
                    case 5:

                    break;
                }
            fp.setDate(date);
            }
        })
    ]
});
```

});